# Prove that all constant functions are in a linear subspace of $C([a,b])$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Given the space $C([a,b])$ (the collection of all real-valued, continuous (with
respect to the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$) functions defined on
the interval $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$), along with the uniform norm and the metric based
on this norm. So we have $(C([a,b]),\rho)$ with $\rho(f,g)=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ for
$f,g\in C([a,b])$.

Next, for $\mu\in \mathbb{R}\setminus [a,b]$, we define $f_{\mu}(x)=1/(\mu-x)\in C([a,b])$ for $x\in[a,b]$, and we denote $V$ the linear subspace of $C([a,b])$ generated by $\{f_{\mu}\ :\ \mu\in \mathbb{R}\setminus [a,b]\}$.

Finally we denote $\overline{V}$ the closure of $V$ (with respect to $\rho$).

Proof that $\mathbf{1}(x):=1$ is in $\overline{V}$.

I tried proving this by generating a sequence of linear combinations of $f_\mu$'s
that converges to $\mathbf{1}$, but
I got stuck. Help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I'm right now trying to prove that the product of two functions in $V$ is in $\overline{V}$ (1), and that the product of two functions in $\overline{V}$ is also in $\overline{V}$ (2). 
I reduced the first to proving that $f_{\mu 1}f_{\mu 2}\in \overline{V}$.
I then tried to find some function $g$ in $V$ so that $\rho(f_{\mu 1}f_{\mu 2},g)<\epsilon$ for all given $\epsilon>0$. Am I on the right track doing this? Because
so far I don't seem able to find the appropriate $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sequence you're looking for is for example given by
$$f_n = \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n - x}$$
for any $\mu_n$ with $\mu_n \rightarrow \infty$. do you think you can show this works?

Comment: Can't believe I did not see this! Thanks a lot.